# Which version of WHERE clause of MySQL is the best?

Tags: mysql, sql, where-clause

Which version of WHERE is the best to use in MySQL? Result is the same. Is there any difference in speed or efficiency or in something else?

WHERE NOT OR:

```
SELECT Country
FROM Customers
WHERE NOT (Country = 'Argentina' OR Country = 'Brazil')
GROUP BY Country
```

WHERE <> AND:

```
SELECT Country
FROM Customers
WHERE (Country <> 'Argentina' AND Country <> 'Brazil')
GROUP BY Country
```

WHERE != AND:

```
SELECT Country
FROM Customers
WHERE (Country != 'Argentina' AND Country != 'Brazil')
GROUP BY Country
```

WHERE NOT LIKE AND:

```
SELECT Country
FROM Customers
WHERE (Country NOT LIKE 'Argentina' AND Country NOT LIKE 'Brazil')
GROUP BY Country
```

[Here](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_select_all) it can be tried.

Comment: None of the above. In the absence of any aggregating functions, a GROUP BY clause is never appropriate. Further, it's almost always quicker to test this kind of thing for yourself. (Hint: the LIKE option is the worst)

Comment: `!=` is nothing but a deprecated version of `<>`. Stick to the latter one!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All 4 of your queries are logically identical, and in fact all 4 queries may have an identical execution plan.  Try running `EXPLAIN` to see for yourself.  The bigger issue here then is code craft, and towards that point, I prefer none of the above, but rather this `WHERE IN` version:

```sql
SELECT Country
FROM Customers
WHERE Country NOT IN ('Argentina', 'Brazil')
GROUP BY Country
```

Answer (score 2):

Use whichever you are most comfortable with.  They are all equivalent -- or at least equivalent under most reasonable circumstances.  However, `like` would not the the same, for instance, if the strings had any wildcards.  Note:  `like` without wildcards should still use an index, so even performance should be similar.

However, I would recommend:

```
where country not in ('Argentina', 'Brazil')
```

I think it most concisely captures the logic you want.